# Intellij + maven jetty plugin vs eclipse + jetty hot deploy?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3, maven-jetty-plugin

I have eclipse and intellij from the same workspace because both replies on pom.xml file. I notice something different. In eclipse, when I setup Jetty Webapp under Run Configurations  and run jetty it looks at /classes folder  for any changes if some of the projects are open (I have about 15 projects, some of them closed some of them open). If some of the projects are not open it will look at jar files from .m2 folder which is fine. So, when I change something I could just compile the file and see the changes without restarting the server.

However, in Intellij CE when I run jetty:run from maven it only looks at .m2 folder for the jar files, so I had to `mvn clean install` every time to update .m2 folder and restart the server. How could I achieve the same thing in IntelliJ? So, when I change something in Java classes I don't have to restart the server?

Comment: Have you checked that it will run with only the package phase? By default the jetty:run goal will look in the ${project.build.outputDirectory} (usually /target) for the items to deploy. I might also suggest using the Intellij Jetty plugin if you have access to the Ultimate edition.